# Custom URL for project using Apache on Localhost

Tags: laravel, apache

I am XAMPP on my localhost. When I go to `localhost` it's redirecting me to `localhost/dashboard/` That's good.

now, I want If I type `laravel.dev` It's should load the laravel `public` folder

For that I configure `httpd-vhosts` file as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-practice/public/"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

windows `hosts` file like below:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost   
127.0.0.1       laravel.dev
```

now, If I go to `laravel.dev` it's redirecting me to `localhost/dashboard/` location. but its should be redirecting me to laravel `public` folder which is `D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-practice/public/`

can you tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Everything looks correct. I just have a suggestion, try to change `.dev` to something else (like `.local`), some browsers have problem with `.dev`.

Comment: no luck after doing this :(

Answer (score 1):

If everything else is ok then change * to laravel.dev

```
<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-practice/public/"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: let me do this now.

Comment: @creativeartbd your code is redirecting. Check you code.

Comment: Elnur Ibrahim-zade  can you tell me how can fix it?

Comment: @creativeartbd you should review your code. see where it is redirecting. Whitout seeing your project code I can not help you. Search "dahsboard" in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Two important points:

- Always restart apache after edit httpd-vhosts
- Include `NameVirtualHost laravel.dev:80` before `<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>`

**UPDATE**

Xampp has a default index.php on htdocs folder, try deleting this file, because index.php redirects to /dashboard and let me know if worked

Comment: You mean inside this `<` before `VirtualHost laravel.dev:80` ?